# NodeJS Passport Facebook OAuth

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, sequelize.js, facebook-oauth

I've been taking courses and watching tutorials on NodeJS for awhile and decided to put them to good use in an app.

For this project I need users to signup and login in order to store their activity in a database. I used Passport to do this process, the code for this section of the project is this:

```
/****** Passport functions ******/
passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
    db.user.findOne( { where : { idUser : id } }).then(function (err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});

//Facebook
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    //Information stored on config/auth.js
    clientID: configAuth.facebookAuth.clientID,
    clientSecret: configAuth.facebookAuth.clientSecret,
    callbackURL: configAuth.facebookAuth.callbackURL,
    profileFields: ['id', 'emails', 'displayName', 'name', 'gender'] 

}, function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    //Using next tick to take advantage of async properties
    process.nextTick(function () {
        db.user.findOne( { where : { idUser : profile.id } }).then(function (err, user) {
            if(err) {
                return done(err);
            } 
            if(user) {
                return done(null, user);
            } else {
                db.user.create({
                    idUser : profile.id,
                    token : accessToken,
                    nameUser : profile.displayName,
                    email : profile.emails[0].value,
                    sex : profile.gender
                });
                return done(null);
            }
        });
    });
}));

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public/'));

/* FACEBOOK STRATEGY */
// Redirect the user to Facebook for authentication.  When complete,
// Facebook will redirect the user back to the application at
//     /auth/facebook/callback//
app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope : ['email']}));
/* FACEBOOK STRATEGY */
// Facebook will redirect the user to this URL after approval.  Finish the
// authentication process by attempting to obtain an access token.  If
// access was granted, the user will be logged in.  Otherwise,
// authentication has failed.
app.get('/auth/facebook/callback', 
    passport.authenticate('facebook', { successRedirect: '/app',
                                      failureRedirect: '/' }));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('/');
});

app.get('/app', isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile('app.html');
});

function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    if(req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return next();
    } else {
        res.redirect('/');
    }
}
```

The tutorial I followed on Facebook Auth using Passport used pretty much the same code, I changed the User model because the tutorial used Mongoose and I'm using [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/) but this aspect is working great, when I click to signup with FB it registers me or logs me in, the queries do the work.

However, what isn't working is the redirection. When I register using facebook, it gets stuck and doesn't load anything (wheel keeps spinning on index.html (where the FB button is) and doesn't load anything). When I login using facebook, it only displays this on the screen:

> [object SequelizeInstance:user]

On the tutorial, the instructor used EJS as a template language,however I already built 95% of the front end of the project using HTML, CSS and jQuery (yeah, should have used React or Angular but time is sensitive and was already learning Node). I believe this is one of the reasons this is happening but I'm not 100% sure on what is going on here and why I'm getting the error or how to get around.

Any help is appreciated, if more information / code is needed, let me know. Thank you

Comment: is this your app.js code?

Comment: did you set `app.use(passport.initialize());` and `app.use(passport.session());` also

Comment: This is my server.js file (not everything, just the passport part) and yes, I did both

Comment: Passport is working, it is signing me up and logging me in, the problem is with the redirection once I'm logged in or signed up.

Comment: what i can suggest is cross check your config files and your local strategy, there might be something wrong. And it's not an EJS issue, cause EJS is just the view part.

Comment: I dont have a local strategy on this app. Let me go through step by step of what I think is going on:

-- Click to use FB Auth
-- app.get('/auth/facebook', gets called
-- returns with success (because I get back the profile info)
-- app.get('/auth/facebook/callback', 
    passport.authenticate('facebook', { successRedirect: '/app',
                                      failureRedirect: '/' })); gets called

Now for some reason the successRedirect doesnt work. Any ideas on why?

Comment: I've encountered an issue like this before, but I didn't find a reason why `successRedirect` didn't work. The code didn't reveal anything. I just wrote a callback with `res.redirect` to get around it.

Comment: Gibryon Bhojraj could you give me an example of writing a callback around it? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after a good amount of time debugging and with some good help, I figured out what was causing my problem, there were actually three errors in there.

First of all, in the Facebook Strategy, this is how I should had built it:

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
    //Information stored on config/auth.js
    clientID: configAuth.facebookAuth.clientID,
    clientSecret: configAuth.facebookAuth.clientSecret,
    callbackURL: configAuth.facebookAuth.callbackURL,
    profileFields: ['id', 'emails', 'displayName', 'name', 'gender'] 

}, function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
    //Using next tick to take advantage of async properties
    process.nextTick(function () {
        db.user.findOne( { where : { idUser : profile.id } }).then(function (user, err) {
            if(err) {
                return done(err);
            } 
            if(user) {
                return done(null, user);
            } else {
                //Create the user
                db.user.create({
                    idUser : profile.id,
                    token : accessToken,
                    nameUser : profile.displayName,
                    email : profile.emails[0].value,
                    sex : profile.gender
                });

                //Find the user (therefore checking if it was indeed created) and return it
                db.user.findOne( { where : { idUser : profile.id } }).then(function (user, err) {
                    if(user) {
                        return done(null, user);
                    } else {
                        return done(err);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
}));
```

The callback after db.user.findOne had switched parameters, so it was giving me an error every time even though it didn't have one, so I switched those and also added a query to look for the user in the DB after creating it to be able to return it.

On the second facebook route, this is how I built it:

```
app.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
    passport.authenticate('facebook', { failureRedirect: '/' }),
    function(req, res) {
        // Successful authentication, redirect home.
        res.redirect('../../app.html');
    });
```

This allowed me to continue using HTML (I'll probably rewrite it to use a better view later on), and on testing, I was able to get the information from req.user.

Finally, I had a minor naming error on Passport's serializeUser:

```
passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user.idUser);
});
```

Just changing from user.id to user.idUser to maintain the naming convention I used.

Hopefully this helps other people using Sequelize with Passport.